# C# Method Overload

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

Recently I started my steps with C # and I have been reading about method overload. I have the following code as a method extension within a class that I named Utilities:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Classes
{
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this Control parent)
        {
            Stack<Control> stack = new Stack<Control>();

            stack.Push(parent);

            while (stack.Any())
            {
                var next = stack.Pop();

                foreach (Control child in next.Controls)
                {
                    stack.Push(child);
                }

                yield return next;
            }
        }
}
```

This method allows me to obtain all controls within a specific control. Amazing!
I can make a call to this method as follows:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 foreach (Control control in TabControl.SelectedTab.GetAllChildren())
 {
   MessageBox.Show(control.Name);
 }
}
```

and as I expected ... I can go through each of the controls within a specific control. (In this case ... TabControl)

**My question is this:**
How can I make this method a method overload?, so that I accept as a first argument a List of several controls, and execute this same method on each of them and return it as a single collection that can iterate

Example:
I want to do something similar to the following:

```
private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Control> controls = new List<Control> {
        TabControl1,
        TabControl2
    };

    foreach (Control control in controls.GetAllChildren())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(control.Name);
    }
}
```

Please, I would appreciate any help .. Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT 1:**

In my Utilities Class I have created a new method with the same name and the class looks like this, but I don't know how to write the logic of that method to perform the action I expect ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BASCAL.Classes
{
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this Control parent)
        {
            Stack<Control> stack = new Stack<Control>();

            stack.Push(parent);

            while (stack.Any())
            {
                var next = stack.Pop();

                foreach (Control child in next.Controls)
                {
                    stack.Push(child);
                }

                yield return next;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this List<Control> parents)
        {
            if (parents.Any())
            {
                // Logic goes here!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are these two processes any different? Method overload normally means redefining a generic method already built in (such as ToString()).. you would override that method.

Comment: What you seem to want to do is create another extension method with `this List<Control>` as first parameter? Though it's unclear what problem you have with that

Comment: @Jawad you are mixing up overloading and `override`ing - they are two different things

Comment: @UnholySheep you are right! Please, if you were so kind to see my first edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be pretty straight forward, and you can reuse your existing logic for convenience. You'll want to declare another extension method that accepts an `IEnumerable<Control>` instead of just a control.

You'll then get the controls for each control in the list, which will result in a list of lists. You then want to flatten that into a single list of `Control`. You can accomplish that with LINQ's `SelectMany`.

The following should work:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this IEnumerable<Control> controls) => controls.SelectMany(GetAllChildren);
```

Alongside your original definition of `GetAllChildren`, you now have an overloaded method. One accepts a single `Control` as it's parameter, the other accepts an `IEnumerable<Control>` as it's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this IEnumerable<Control> parents)
{
    return parents.SelectMany(p => p.GetAllChildren());
}
```

Add another extension that accepts a collection of controls.

You can reuse the existing extension method for each control in the list, and use LINQ `SelectMany` to combine the children into a single collection.

Comment: Incredible, you are the savior of my day .. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

While your original method's signature is

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this Control parent)
```

the signature of should be

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this IEnumerable<Control> parents)
```

I made up an example with integer nubmbers:

```
struct Foo
{
    public int[] parts;
}

void Main()
{
    Foo f1 = new Foo() { parts = new int[] {3, 6, 9}};
    Foo f2 = new Foo() { parts = new int[] {4, 40, 400, 4000}};
    Foo f3 = new Foo() { parts = new int[] {3, 33, 333}};
    var fooList = new List<Foo>() { f2, f3 };

    foreach (var element in tellFoo(f1))
        Console.WriteLine(element);

    foreach (var element in tellFoo(fooList))
        Console.WriteLine(element);
}

IEnumerable<int> tellFoo(Foo x)
{
    foreach (var element in x.parts)
        yield return element;
}

IEnumerable<int> tellFoo(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
    foreach (var foo in foos)
        foreach (var element in tellFoo(foo))
            yield return element;
}
```

So we have two overloads that both return one element at a time. The second one uses the first.

Comment: This would return `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Control>>`.

Comment: Well, that's what you get for replying quickly and not thoughtfully ... You're right, @Jonathan. I worked out an example with ints that's working and I put it in the place of my answer.